# How to change the edit style to ES_NUMBER at run time?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

While creating the edit control, I do not add the `ES_NUMBER`. later based on a boolean flag, I want to change the style and make it `ES_NUMBER` and revert it back on the other value of the boolean flag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775464.aspx) has the answer. Some excerpts:

> To create an edit control using the CreateWindow or CreateWindowEx function, specify the EDIT class, appropriate window style constants, and a combination of the following edit control styles. After the control has been created, these styles cannot be modified, except as noted.

So, we may or may not be able to change style after creating the control. Let's see:

> **ES_NUMBER**
>
> Allows only digits to be entered into the edit control. Note that, even with this set, it is still possible to paste non-digits into the edit control.
>
> To change this style after the control has been created, use SetWindowLong.
>
> To translate text that was entered into the edit control to an integer value, use the GetDlgItemInt function. To set the text of the edit control to the string representation of a specified integer, use the SetDlgItemInt function.

To add the style do this:

```
LONG style = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE);
SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, style | ES_NUMBER);
```

Or to remove it:

```
LONG style = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE);
SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, style & ~ES_NUMBER);
```

Comment: I'd recommend going with [SetWindowLongPtr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644898.aspx) instead. It won't make a difference here, but following the *always use `SetWindowLongPtr`* rule will be the safe choice where it does matter.